# rails rvm path error when logout terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

i have run a rails project on my server, and i use ssh to connect server to start/stop/restart rails project with terminal, if i do not close the terminal, it run well, but when i close the terminal, the project begin to raise error like(but not always):

LoadError (cannot load such file -- devise/parameter_filter)
....

and so on.

when i lsof the process, i found the rvm path is change,

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
ruby    18168   wacom  cwd    DIR  252,0      4096  2108629 /app/service/wacom/releases/20131215130012
ruby    18168   wacom  rtd    DIR  252,0      4096        2 /
ruby    18168   wacom  txt    REG   0,22    112181   139104 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
ruby    18168   wacom  mem    REG   0,22    220552  1053141 /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.1.2/lib/bcrypt_ext.so
.........
```

but when i keep the terminal open, it run well, and lsof result is

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
ruby    18168   wacom  cwd    DIR  252,0      4096  2108629 /app/service/wacom/releases/20131215130012
ruby    18168   wacom  rtd    DIR  252,0      4096        2 /
ruby    18168   wacom  txt    REG   0,22    112181   139104 /home/wacom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
ruby    18168   wacom  mem    REG   0,22    220552  1053141 /home/wacom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.1.2/lib/bcrypt_ext.so
.......
```

i have set [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" on .bashrc and have source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

anyone has the same problem or can help me? thx!!

Comment: how do you run your project script?

Comment: unicorn_rails -E production -D -c config/unicorn.rb

Comment: try create run script on bash that will setup rvm env and then run unicorn (without detach). but you have to run the scripr with `nohup`

Comment: i had try it, but seems not useful...

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env bash
# enter into rvm...
unicorn_rails -E production -c config/unicorn.rb

Comment: then `hohup run_script`

Comment: how to write the code  "#enter into rvm" ... my rvm path is /home/wacom/.rvm

Comment: as well as it has been written in your **.bash_rc**

Comment: then add line to use rvm like `rvm use ...`

Comment: so
`#!/usr...; 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"; 
rvm use....
unicord_rails...`

Comment: and call to the script: `nohup script`

Comment: if you'll plan to ruby fom startup, add `-l` key after bash in 1st line

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env bash
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm";
rvm use 2.0.0;
unicorn_rails -E production -c config/unicorn.rb;

Comment: i had run this script as u say, but not useful..

Comment: Get rid of `$HOME` and `~` in your scripts (change them to explicit `/home/wacom`.) Ruby stores the RVM pathes as is and evaluates the expression every time it needs it. When `$HOME` became empty, you got an error.

Comment: i had already try to change $HOME to /home/wacom， problems still exist

Comment: Then try `HOME=$HOME unicorn_rails -E production -c config/unicorn.rb`

Comment: @cway please show the script and call as you've used in your post

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env bash  [[ -s "/home/ec/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/home/ec/.rvm/scripts/rvm";   rvm use 2.0.0;  unicorn_rails -E production -c config/unicorn.rb;  this is my script and i execute it with  nohup run_script.sh

Comment: It runs unicorn, and what happens?

Comment: when i close the terminal, relogin the app server and lsof the rails project pid, rvm path  changed to /.rvm/.....( correct, it should be /home/wacom/.. ), and begin to raise 'LoadError (cannot load such file'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that our server system has used `ecryptfs`,so when user logout, the user dir will umount, then system can not found the rvm path in user dir and redirect to /.rvm ! thanks all to answer my question!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use wrappers, they will ensure proper ruby environment, since rvm 1.25 it is:

```
ls `gem env gemhome`/wrappers/unicorn_rails
```

also check example scripts for working with rvm and ruby environment => http://rvm.io/integration/init-d